# What is the expiration date of patent US9474214?

Tags: expiration

What is the expiration date of patent [US9474214](https://www.google.com/patents/US9474214)?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine the expiration date of a US patent is at the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. Go to Pair, get past the CAPTCHA and then select "Patent Number" and enter 9474214. Pair is extremely picky about format so don't add any commas. From there you can find that this patent will expire 20 years from it's filing or 371(c) date of 09-07-2012 plus 523 days of patent term adjustment. If I calculate correctly that ends up with an expiration date of **February 12, 2034**.

Comment: We almost need a general, self-answered question on this topic *(although I suspect very few OP's actually search for prior questions;)*

Comment: @DukeZhou Agreed. Why don't you take a whack at it. If you make it a public wiki, then others can add content. For instance, I have a good take on US patents, but I'm not sure if there are things like patent term extensions for foreign patents or how to find out.